# I would like to track my next Socratic badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

I understand the [Socratic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) badge can be achieved multiple times. If that's the case, I'd like to be able to track my next Socratic badge - right now it seems I can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

The badge is awarded when you

> Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) for this.

For example, the query "[Progress towards Curious, Inquisitive and Socratic badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges)" tells me that [you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1593077/einpoklum) (user ID = 1593077) have 137 qualifying questions. In other words, you have 200 - 137 = 63 questions to go.

---

Note that their [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) says:

> **How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC.

Comment: Thanks, I should have upvoted you earlier. However, I still think you should be able to track the badge repeatedly through the user information UI, with the bar-filling charts.

Comment: Yeah, I would probably agree with you there - it would be nice.